# What could be the reason for Node js chat application being slower than Java?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to Node js and I've built a very simple group chat application with Mongodb in both node js (using socket.io library and express) and Java (websockets from Javalin.io library). They basically do the same exact things so I would expect the Node js one to be faster than the Java one, as this is probably the best example of a real time and I/O based application.

However, testing the applications with JMeter (N requests in 5 seconds) shows that the Node js app is slightly slower for lower N (50-100), becoming even much slower for higher N (400).

The request I'm testing is an HTTP request to an api returning a Json array containing all the messages in the mongodb:

```
app.all('/chats', function (req, res) {
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.statusCode = 200;

thechatsCollection.find({}).toArray ( (err, chats) => {
    var jsonArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        jsonArr.push({
        sender: chats[i].sender,
        message: chats[i].message,
        createdAt: chats[i].createdAt
        });
    }
    res.json(jsonArr);
    });
});
```

I initialize thechatsCollection once, when the server starts and I know that it should open a dynamic pool of connections (starting with 5), which is exactly the same in the Java implementation.

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat", { useNewUrlParser: true, /*poolSize: 100*/ }, (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    client.db('chat').collection('thechats', (err, collection) => {
        thechatsCollection = collection;
        console.log("connected to the db");
    });                    
});
```

In addition, I noticed that running the test a second time results in a lower mean of response time, which I thought was due to the connection pool to the db being increased, so I tried to set the poolSize parameter when opening the db connection (to 10,20,50,100) but it mostly made things slower.

Is it possible a node js implementation of a chat app is slower than the java one? What could be the reason for this? Am I writing the asynchronous part wrong?

Java implementation of the rest request:

```
app.get("/chats", ctx -> {
        JSONArray messageArray = getMessageArray();
        ctx.contentType("application/json");
        ctx.result(messageArray.toString());
    });

// Builds a JSON array containing all the messages in the db
private static JSONArray getMessageArray() {
    JSONArray messageArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Document doc : thechatsCollection.find()) {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        message.put("message", doc.get("message"));
        message.put("sender", doc.get("sender"));
        message.put("createdAt", doc.get("createdAt"));
        messageArray.put(message);
    }
    return messageArray;
}
```

I tried profiling with the built in `--prof`, calling `ab -c 20 -n 250 "http://localhost:5000/chats"`, which should perform 250 requests 20 at a time, and processing the file with `--prof-process` and this is what i get:

```
 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    606    2.2%   78.3%  JavaScript
      0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
    298    1.1%   38.5%  GC
  26331   97.1%          Shared libraries
    168    0.6%          Unaccounted
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  23282   85.9%          C:/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
   3026   11.2%          C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe
...
 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    122    0.5%   15.8%  LazyCompile: *deserializeObject C:/Users/apon9/OneDrive/Node js/chatApplication_nodejs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/deserializer.js:41:33
     82    0.3%   10.6%  Builtin: KeyedStoreIC_Megamorphic
     35    0.1%    4.5%  Builtin: InterpreterEntryTrampoline
...
```

`C:/Program Files/Nodejs/Node.exe` seems reasonable to me, but I have no idea if `C:/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll` is supposed to be there with 86%, maybe kernel related?

How about `deserializeObject`? Is my code optimizable in any way?

Comment: What does the Java implementation of this rest request look like?

Comment: Added the java implementation

Answer (score 1):

node is *apparently* fast with asynchronous mechanism and non-blocking IOs (like for MongoDB queries in your case), with synchronous code Java could beat JS.

First, without Java source code, your JS is using `push`, and that is synchronous. Depending on the number of messages, it might already take quite some time (1M push might take ~20ms), and multiply that by 50 concurrency it becomes a problem)

Secondly, as for why bigger pool is slower, this is likely because MongoClient pool is initializing connection lazily, meaning that the connection is initialized only on first query of each connection. With a bigger pool, more connections needs to be initialized first. So for example, with pool size of 100, your first 100 queries will be slow because those queries will wait for the connection to establish. But then subsequently the one with pool size 100 should be able to give lower average response time *under high concurrency*.

So comparing with Java, in particular your implementation. If your implementation does not use `push`, and your Mongo client actively creates connection during pool initialization, your Java may well be able to beat *this JS implementation*, especially during the early requests.

Comment: 1) How is `push` a synchronous operation? What is the asynchronous way to add an item to an array?
2) Is there any way to initialize the connections of the connection pool in an eager way rather than lazy? What is the point of setting the `poolSize` ?

Comment: There is no asynchronous way to add to an array and it would not be faster if you did. The point was more that your code is doing some math here, building these arrays, and Java might be faster at that. Probably is, since it's strongly typed. But is this really where the time is going? Nobody really knows, and nobody will until you start profiling the code.

Comment: Oh thanks, I get the point now. I just tried profiling my node js app using the built in profiler, but i have some trouble... will edit the op right now if have any idea about it